# iOS CoreData convert string for the languages different to english

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

So the problem is minor. I have NSString the one attribute of my entity. When I work with string on english CoreData store it with the same symbols. But using different languages it starts to store string as:

```
"\U041c\U0430\U0440\U0442\U0438\U043d - \U0427\U0438\U0441\U0442\U044b\U0439 \U043a\U043e\U0434.2010.pdf"
```

So what's the problem here: of course I am using predicate for getting some entities and if the predicate equal to the string then it return me object. But when I using not english symbols I get error because the core data automatically convert symbols to the anther string (excluding English).

So what's the steps to fix it? Do I need to check the language before using predicate or there is another simple solution that can help me?

So the predicate looks like:

NSPredicate *predicate
    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@ AND \
       %K == %@",
       kPNFolder_Path, folderPath,
       kPNFile_FileName, @"China symbols or Cyrillic symbols here"];

But core data store it as I have described above. Of course it will not return any values, because there is no matches, because of conversation symbols to the unicode after set value to the entity.

Comment: Those are Unicode characters.

Comment: @user1256663 thanks for comment but the searching string I mean about string is not in unicode. How can I convert it to unicode?

Comment: I think NSString is already unicode if you are putting them in from @"XX". How did you enter your string and how did you retrieve from core data as a string? And how did you log? I usually use initWithData:encoding: to get NSData obtained from server and convert to NSString for UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: i have to use predicate for filtering my objects. so when i set string for entity it looks like @"aaa" or @"ooo" for example, but when I check my entity object it prints \U0438\U0438\U0438 instead of three Cyrillic characters. But when I check string it prints @"aaa" for me. I am not sure if a - it is \U0438 just select it for example, but in any case I can't filter my object using predicate because predicate strings and stored strings are different.

Comment: the whole entity object prints the data of the string objects, so it's correct for you to see \U0438\U0438\U0438. Predicate should work with NSString with different languages as I tested. I think the problem is on your predicateWithFormat. You can try filtering a with an entity and attribute using English and make sure it works first.

Comment: @user1256663 in English it works good, but in Russian it does not. The predicate looks like @"привет", but core data store this string as \U0438 and etc